# Is there an IRC client for Ubuntu with inline media?

Tags: software-recommendation, media, irc

Does any IRC client exist for Ubuntu which displays media inline (perhaps via plugin)?

A few IRC clients for Mac OS X (e.g. [Textual](http://www.codeux.com/textual/) and [LimeChat](http://limechat.net/mac/)) support inline media and will auto-embed linked images: if someone posts a URL to the channel, the IRC client displays it inline if it is able to be embedded, like a .jpg or .png image. However, I cannot find a client for Ubuntu with this feature.

The closest I can find is [Quassel](http://www.quassel-irc.org/), which can display a URL preview *on mouse hover*, but that's not the feature I'm requesting and the webkit support for this preview is not enabled in the Ubuntu packaged build on 12.04.

To illustrate: without the feature, you get just text:

```
<rduplain> | askubuntu.com
<bot     > | https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTVCH.png
<rduplain> | good luck
```

---

With the feature, the chat view is expanded and the image is inserted:

```
<rduplain> | askubuntu.com
<bot     > | https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPbDF.png
```

[image: askubuntu.com]

```
<rduplain> | good luck
```

Comment: Quassel is the closest I know of. Perhaps someone will have better advice. Also, you may wish to add a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: The smuxi feature request is [here](https://www.smuxi.org/issues/show/747). I think my markdown mockup illustrates this, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Lounge](https://thelounge.github.io) will let you do that through its link prefetching mechanism. For the record, link previews currently look like this:
[image: Link prefetching of The Lounge]

This screenshot is part of the whole app, which looks like this:[image]

FYI, the author from Subway (mentioned in the other answer) [now recommends to use The Lounge](https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway#subway).

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin supports IRC as well as a number of different protocols.

[This patch](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/pidgin-embedded-video-now-with-image.html) for [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-embeddedvideo/) seems to be what you are looking for:

[image]

The screenshots are from different protocols, but it should work with IRC too. I haven't tried it since I don't use Pidgin and it requires some dependencies I also don't have.

Another suggestion is [Subway](https://github.com/thedjpetersen/subway), a web-based IRC. I don't use it either, but it seems to run on Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: Pidgin is an interesting idea, but I prefer a client which has the notion of an IRC main content view with room selection. Subway is an interesting project but is too beta for my taste.